# Determining whether the given series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Which series test may I apply to find if the following series is convergent or divergent? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n^{1/n}+6)^n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparison we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n^{1/n}+6)^{n}}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{6^n}=\frac{6}{25}$$

where the last equality can be obtained by observing that for

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\\\\
=\frac{x}{1-x}
\end{align}$$

we have

$$\begin{align}
xf'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n}\\\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, set $x=1/6$ in $(1)$.

Comment: And how did you get that expression from the final sum? That is not obvious.

Comment: @RoryDaulton There are a couple of ways to go.  For example, differentiate the function with series representation $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$ for get $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$.  Then, multiply by $x$ and set $x=1/6$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\;n $ - th root test as this is a positive series

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac n{\left(\sqrt[n]n+6\right)^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]n}{\sqrt[n]n+6}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{1+6}=\frac17<1$$

Comment: @snulty Thank you very much. That's a serious typo and I will edit now.

Comment: you're welcome :)